# Jovo deploy unable to find ask-clik

Tags: jovo-framework, ask-cli

I am trying to build Alexa skill with Jovo but stuck at one place where jovo deploy is not working. Looking at error it seems like its unable to find ask-cli. Jovo build works fine, plus if i try ask-cli deploy that one also works. The issue seems to be with some configuration, i tried looking at all project files but didn't find any setting which can resolve this issue. Can someone please guide me if i am missing anything here..

```
Steps followed -
1 - jovo new helloworld 
2 - jovo run 
3 - jovo build 
4 - jovo deploy
```

I found few people running ask init but it ask for lambda and skill file path which I don't see available with jovo. i tried comparing jovo files with ask-cli and didn't find matching file for lambda so not sure if this can be issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just workaround, the original issue remain as it is. Workaround is skip this auto deploy process and do everything manually.

1. Based on app.js build Alexa skill (Make sure to have all handler)
2. Create zip file for all files under your jovo folder.
3. Create new lambda function, and upload this file (Enter skill id and add Alexa trigger).
4. Update index.handler path to ./src/index.handler
5. Test code using Alexa Start Session

This seems to be Jovo 2.0 method of deployment, I am just using it as workaround until I find some fix for auto jovo deployment.